# Copying Key / Value Data into Structure

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I am having trouble loading API exchange rates into the structure instance moneyRate. The data in rates is formatted as key / values [String : Double]. At the end of the URLSession notice that I have copied the date and base currency into moneyRates, but I can't seem to do the same for the exchange rates such as something like **moneyRates.rates = rates**. I can see the data in rates in the console.

```
struct MoneyRates {
    var date: String
    var base: String
    var rates: [String: Double]
}

class CurrencyRates: ObservableObject {
    
    var moneyRates = MoneyRates(date: "2020-07-04", base: "usd", rates: ["bzd": 0.0, "cnh": 0.0, "bbd": 0.0, "hkd": 0.0, "bmd": 0.0, "amd": 0.0, "inr": 0.0, "gmd": 0.0, "ang": 0.0, "egp": 0.0, "cdf": 0.0, "bif": 0.0, "lak": 0.0, "cop": 0.0, "cve": 0.0, "gtq": 0.0, "hrk": 0.0])
    
    // retrieve exchange rates for all 150+ countries from internet and save to rateArray
    func updateRates(baseCur: String) {
        
        print("doing update")
        
        let baseUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/"
        let requestType = ".json"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + baseCur + requestType) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
                    
                    var keys = Array(result.keys)
                    if let dateIndex = keys.firstIndex(of: "date"),
                       let date = result[keys[dateIndex]] as? String, keys.count == 2 {
                        keys.remove(at: dateIndex)
                        let base = keys.first!
                        let rates = MoneyRates(date: date, base: base, rates: result[base] as! [String:Double])
                        
                       
                        moneyRates.date = date
                        moneyRates.base = base
                        print(rates) // displays all key / value exchange rates
                     
                        }                       
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On first analysis, I thought that I could set **moneyRates.rates = rates**.

But when that didn't work, I looked above at how the **base** and **date** were being pulled out of **result** and thought that I could do the same for the exchange rates.

So the solution is **moneyRates.rates = result[base] as! [String : Double]**.

```
class CurrencyRates: ObservableObject {
    
    var moneyRates = MoneyRates(date: "2020-07-04", base: "usd", rates: ["bzd": 0.0, "cnh": 0.0, "bbd": 0.0, "hkd": 0.0, "bmd": 0.0, "amd": 0.0, "inr": 0.0, "gmd": 0.0, "ang": 0.0, "egp": 0.0, "cdf": 0.0, "bif": 0.0, "lak": 0.0, "cop": 0.0, "cve": 0.0, "gtq": 0.0, "hrk": 0.0])
    
    // retrieve exchange rates for all 150+ countries from internet and save to rateArray
    func updateRates(baseCur: String) {
        
        print("doing update")
        
        let baseUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/"
        let requestType = ".json"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + baseCur + requestType) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
            
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]
                    
                    var keys = Array(result.keys)
                    if let dateIndex = keys.firstIndex(of: "date"),
                       let date = result[keys[dateIndex]] as? String, keys.count == 2 {
                        keys.remove(at: dateIndex)
                        let base = keys.first!
                   
                        moneyRates.date = date
                        moneyRates.base = base
                        moneyRates.rates = result[base] as! [String : Double]
                     
                        }                       
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```